# Autocorrelation in timesearies analysis, tails off or cuts off after q

Tags: python, time-series

I have been confused when analysed a time series. I'm wondering whether it is
"cuts off after lag 52" or "tails off" in this acf and pacf?

[image: acf]

[image: pacf]

Comment: Can you elaborate on that question? What do you cite with "cuts off after lag 52" or "tails off"? What is the code/method behind these plots?

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this kind of question.

Comment: @elcombato Thanks, elcombato! As koalo said, [nice thread at Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241914/terms-cut-off-and-tail-off-about-acf-pacf-functions) gives a good explanation.

Comment: @Dirk Thanks for your tip,  i'll try it next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For understanding the basics about "tail off" and "cut off", see this [nice thread at Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241914/terms-cut-off-and-tail-off-about-acf-pacf-functions).

However, in your example it is difficult to see in your picture if it is a tail off or a cut off between 0 and 20. From the strict definition I would say it is a (non-exponential) tail off, but it could also be random since it is very near to the boundary.

However, between 20 and 52 all values are within the shaded area, so it is not a "cut off after 52". At least if you want to model it as ARMA process, the spike at 52 can probably not be modeled very well.

Comment: You're so good, koalo. Looks like this series is not suitable for ARMA, right?

Comment: It is not an ARMA process, but nevertheless a prediction using ARMA might be sufficient for your application. You should try it out.